# Is using tasks in Outlook 365 okay

Tags: c#, asynchronous, outlook, task, vsto

I have read in Microsoft documentation that i should access Outlook com objects only from main thread otherwise I would gets exceptions. I'm developing outlook vsto for document workflow. VSTO adds Workflow category to email, allows user to add an email with attachment to Workflow, prevents removing Workflow category for email added to Workflow and to reach this i have to keeping all emails in list (for keeping firing events) which i load on start which takes some time, that's why i used Tasks.

Here is the code.
Can I leave it the way it its?

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        _wfMailItems = new Dictionary<string, MailItem>();
        _notWfMailItems = new Dictionary<string, MailItem>();
        _isLoaded = false;
        TryToLoadAddon();

    }

    private void TryToLoadAddon()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {

            if (CheckIfWFMailboxIsAvaible())
            {
                LoadMailItemsAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Brak dostępu do skrzynki: {ApprovedWfMailbox}. Dodatek nie zostanie załadowany.", "Dodatek WorkFlow", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        });
    }

    private bool CheckIfWFMailboxIsAvaible()
    {
        return !(_explorer.Session.Folders.OfType<MAPIFolder>().FirstOrDefault(fold => fold.Name.Equals(ApprovedWfMailbox)) == null);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// It does all the tasks on Addin Startup
    /// Adds WorkFlowCategory
    /// Loads mailItems to lists
    /// Adds events
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadMailItemsAsync()
    {
        object arg = _isLoaded;

        var task = Task.Run(() =>
         {

             AddBeforeFolderSwitchEvent();
             AddWorkFlowCategory(ApprovedWfMailbox);
             LoadWorkFlowMailItems();
             LoadNotWfMailitems();
             AddEventsToEachWorkFlowMailItem();
             AddEventsToEachNotWorkFlowMailItem();
             AddQuitEvent();



         }).ContinueWith(delegate
         {
             arg = true;
             lock (isLoadedLock)
             {
                 _isLoaded = (bool)arg;
                 RemoveBeforeFolderSwitchEvent();
             }

         }, arg);

    }

    private void LoadWorkFlowMailItems()
    {
        var mailBox = _explorer.Session.Folders.OfType<MAPIFolder>().FirstOrDefault(fold => fold.Name.Equals(ApprovedWfMailbox));
        var inBox = mailBox.Store.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        foreach (var item in inBox.Items)
        {
            if (item is MailItem mailItem)
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailItem.Categories))
                    if (mailItem.Categories.Contains(WorkFlowCategoryName))
                    {
                        _wfMailItems.Add(mailItem.EntryID, mailItem);
                    }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: I think the bigger question is _is it OK to do complex things in a constructor?_ to which the answer is generally "no" -  _["A constructor should do as little as possible"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/224065/125248)_ .  Surely VSTO has `virtual` methods you can override?

Comment: Good point, any suggestion is appreciated! But in constructor I just run task which is not awaited there. Which methods do you have in mind? @MickyD

Answer (score 0):

Using tasks is fine until OOM objects are used on secondary threads.

Don't keep mail item objects in a dictionary. Instead, you can use the `EntryID` property value which can be used for getting a mail item instance where required. The [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method returns a Microsoft Outlook item identified by the specified entry ID (if valid). A MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store. Therefore, the `EntryID` property is not set for an Outlook item until it is saved or sent. The Entry ID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder, or from one Personal Folders (.pst) file to another .pst file. Solutions should not depend on the `EntryID` property to be unique unless items will not be moved. Si, additionally you may be interested in handling the item's move operations.

Another aspect is that you are iterating over all items in the folder which is also not a really good solution.

```
  foreach (var item in inBox.Items)
  {
     if (item is MailItem mailItem)
```

Instead, you may consider using the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)